# Is there any way to get the position of a value in a table returned by a SELECT statement?

Tags: sqlite

I have the following statement:

```
SELECT id FROM myTable WHERE aCondition == 1 ORDER BY id
```

which returns a table like this one for example:

```
id
1
3
4
5
```

But what I need is to know the position of a given number. For example 4 has position 2 in the database.

I can do that with normal C code of course but I wonder if I can do everything in SQL, something like this for example:

```
SELECT ROWNUMBER(id, 4) FROM myTable WHERE aCondition == 1 ORDER BY id
```

which should return:

```
ROWNUMBER
2
```

Comment: What do you mean with ***"position 2"***? Rows do not have specific order, unless you specify one (do you mean position 2 when ordered by `id`?)

Comment: yes, exactly that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a `ROW_NUMBER()` analytic function but I don't think it's available in SQLite. So, here's a generic approach (which may be quite slow):

```
SELECT pos - 1 AS ROWNUMBER     --- the "-1" is to get the C-style row numbering
FROM
  ( SELECT b.id
         , COUNT(*) AS pos 
    FROM myTable AS a
      JOIN myTable AS b
        ON a.id <= b.id 
    WHERE a.aCondition = 1
      AND b.aCondition = 1
      AND a.id <= 4             --- optional for  
      AND b.id <= 4             --- performace 
    GROUP BY b.id
  ) AS tmp
WHERE id = 4
```

Note that you should not use the additional two lines (checks), if your final `WHERE` checks for something else than `id`.

---

Rethinking, there's an even better way, because you only want the Row_Number of the last element in that list. There is no need to number them all, we can just count them:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN maxid = 4     --- so we don't get a RowNumber for an @id
              THEN cnt-1       --- that does not meet the condition
              ELSE NULL        --- or is not in the table at all 
       END AS ROWNUMBER    
FROM
  ( SELECT MAX(id)  AS maxid
         , COUNT(*) AS cnt 
    FROM myTable AS a
    WHERE a.aCondition = 1
      AND a.id <= 4   
  ) AS tmp
```